# how to add docker disk space without recreating a new container?

Tags: docker

I've recently learned that there is a disk limit of docker containers, on my system it is 50GB. I wonder if there is a way to bump up the disk limit for the same container, without creating a new one.

I created the container as this:

```
nvidia-docker run -dit -v host_dir:docker_local_dir -p 5000:8080 --name  Test_Container --privileged Test_Image /bin/bash
```

after detaching from the container (probably a bad idea!), I wasn't able to attach it anymore:

```
$nvidia-docker exec -it Test_Container /bin/bash
Error response from daemon: Container ada1..230032 is not running
```

I really don't want to create a new container and redo lots of logistics. 
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `docker start container` will start stopped container.

Comment: Thanks! @NiVeR, that helped restart the container, but still look for a way to increase the disk space there

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't expand the size further. Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/):

> $ sudo dockerd --storage-opt dm.basesize=50G
>
> This will increase the base device size to 50G. The Docker daemon will
>   throw an error if existing base device size is larger than 50G. A user
>   can use this option to expand the base device size however shrinking
>   is not permitted.

To overcome this, what you should do is to map the particular folder of the container, that you know that will go high in size, to a location in the host OS (as you seem to be doing in the command). You can do it like this:

```
docker run -v /host/path/tmp:container/path/tmp
```

With which you are saying that everything that should be saved in `container/path/tmp` should be instead saved in `/host/path/tmp`. In this way you don't have any limits, other than the physical ones of the machine. With this approach you must recreate the container.

Comment: not sure of the rationale for such a limit, looks to me this would restrict the way containers are used. In this case, essentially we should rely on shared volumes between host and container to access to anything that's reasonably large? a bit surprised by this.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution by Docker per se, seems that's not feasible yet. 
But to avoid recreating a new container, i found that as long as the 'host_dir' is not local (e.g., gpfs dir etc), you have a good chance to mount it within Docker:

```
mount -v -t cifs [network folder address/path] [mount folder] -o user=[user id/name],sec=ntlm
```

mount options should adjust accordingly.